# Reading a variable as a larger type in C

Tags: c, c99

When reading or writing to a buffer I believe it is common to need to access data which is larger than the type of the buffer (pointer).  I have come up with three distinct approaches so far but I am wondering if there is a language feature for this or an accepted standard practice.  Option `c` provides the most flexibility in that it can handle structures and arrays as well as integral types.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
#define ADDRESS 6

uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] =
{
    [ADDRESS] = 0x37,
    [ADDRESS+1] = 0x42,
};

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t a = buffer[ADDRESS] + (buffer[ADDRESS + 1]<<8);
    uint16_t b = *(buffer + ADDRESS) + (*(buffer + ADDRESS + 1)<<8);
    uint16_t c = *((uint16_t *) (buffer + ADDRESS));

    printf("a: 0x%x\n", a);
    printf("b: 0x%x\n", b);
    printf("c: 0x%x\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not concerned about endianness because all interaction with the buffer is within the single embedded program; external interfaces with endianness safety are provided independently.  The standard of most interest is C99 but references to any are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The first two are equivalent, here `buffer[ADDRESS]` is the same as `*(buffer + ADDRESS)`

```
uint16_t a = buffer[ADDRESS] + (buffer[ADDRESS + 1]<<8);
uint16_t b = *(buffer + ADDRESS) + (*(buffer + ADDRESS + 1)<<8);
```

The last one invokes undefined behavior as it violates C aliasing rules ([C99, 6.5p7](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=80)) and may break alignment:

```
uint16_t c = *((uint16_t *) (buffer + ADDRESS));
```

So to summarize, choose the first one as it is the more readable.

Comment: I understand that much code is more dynamic and would be working with a `void *` from `malloc` instead.  What is the appropriate static alternative?

Comment: @altendky Use memcpy and copy from buffer to a proper local variable. That is allowed.

Comment: @altendky I think I don't get your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ouah If I understand correctly, the aliasing concerns would not be applicable if I had `malloc`ed my buffer since it would then be a `void *`.  If that statement is true then it would seem that there ought to be a static equivalent.  It may be that the way in which I set the values is misleading and my example should have been more complete.  On the other hand, I think that @self's response may be 'the answer'.

Comment: @altendky You have to use malloc, *or* memcpy with local memory.

Comment: @self When I read your comment I felt silly for not having gone straight to `malloc`, but for some reason it didn't come to mind.  Thanks, and if you make it an answer (I have already added it to my Ideone example) I would accept it, otherwise I will do so myself.

Comment: @altendky You can answer it better. Just make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The code for `a` and `b` is equivalent, since `a[i]` is shorthand for `*(a + i)`.

The code for `c` invokes undefined behavior since it might use a non-aligned access. If you *know* that your machine handles unaligned accesses, and have a happy compiler, it might work. It's not recommended though, since it can break unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying activity, regardless of an array buffer or a `malloc`ed buffer, is an arbitrary copying of a number of bytes from one location to another.  The standard means for this is is `memcpy()`.

```
uint16_t d;
memcpy(&d, &buffer[ADDRESS], sizeof(d));
```

The [Ideone example](http://ideone.com/pTo5T9) has been updated.